# Problema con subir imagenes con formato jpg desde android al servidor mysql, solo sube formato png

Tags: php, android

Buenas noches tengo un problema pasa que estoy guardando la imagenes en mi base de datos desde mi android en una columna longblob entonces pues lo que pasa esque me guarda solo formatos PNG, pero yo al seleccionar images desde mi app android en formato jpg pues no me funca alguien sabe el problema? aqui les dejo mi codigo q seria el websercies que si me funciona con PNG pero con JPG nada.

```
  $host_name = "localhost";
  $database = "base_olx";
   $user = "root";
  $password = "";

  $con = mysqli_connect($host_name,$user,$password,$database);

  $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);


 //$nombre = $json["nombre"];
  $nombre = $json["listaNombres"];
  $listaImagen = $json["listaImagen"];
  $elIdProdInmueble = $json["idProdInmueble"];




   $respuesta = array();


   if(isset($listaImagen)){

      if(is_array($listaImagen)){
       $i = 0;
       $u = 1;
       $f = "foto";
       foreach($listaImagen as $imagen){



           $na = $nombre[$i];
           $f = $f.$u;
           $ruta = "../fotos/".$na;
           $imagen = addslashes($imagen);
           $insertarEnGaleria = "INSERT INTO `galeria`(`url`, 
   `id_prod_inmu`,`imagen`, `ruta`) VALUES 
   ('$f','$elIdProdInmueble','$imagen','$ruta')";


           $decodedImagen = base64_decode($imagen);
           $return = file_put_contents("../fotos/".$na,$decodedImagen);
           $i++;


           //$insertarEnGaleria = "INSERT INTO `galeria`(`url`, 
   `id_prod_inmu`,`imagen`, `ruta`) VALUES 
   ('$f','$elIdProdInmueble','$decodedImagen','$ruta')";
            $f = "foto";
            $u++;
            mysqli_query($con,$insertarEnGaleria);

       }

        $respuesta["ok"] = "Imagenes agregadas con exitos";
   }


   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo  json_encode( $respuesta);
  }else{
    $respuesta["ok"] = "Hubo un error fatal";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo  json_encode( $respuesta);
   }
```

gracias amigos puej espero q puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿No habrá en tu servidor o en tu base de datos algún tipo de restricción sobre el tipo de archivo? Convendría que revises el log de errores del servidor y la configuración del archivo `.htaccess`

Comment: estoy usando phpmyadmin y xammp bueno no encuentro ninguno de lo q me mencionas amigo ni log de errores ni .htacces  gracias x responder,.

Comment: El log de errores suele estar en la carpeta donde está tu archivo PHP y se suele llamar `error_log` o algo parecido. Si ordenas por fecha de actualización  aparece por lo general entre los primeros porque se actualiza cada vez que hay un error y los últimos errores aparecen al final. Sería bueno que aprendas a usar ese archivo, te ahorrará horas en la programación porque te dice exactamente dónde falla el código. Si quieres ver por pantalla el error puedes poner esto al inicio de tu script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`